# Covariance of the sum of two random vectors

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, covariance, random

This is the situation. I have an estimation of the position $(x_t,y_t)$ of an object with its covariance $\Sigma_p$ and an estimation of its speed $(v_x, v_y)$ with its covariance $\Sigma_v$. Actually, the two estimations should be correlated since the speed is computed from the position estimation, but for simplicity, we can assume they are independent.

Now, I want to estimate the covariance of the future position of the object $(x_{t+1}, y_{t+1}) = (x_t,y_t) + (v_x, v_y) \cdot dt$, where  $(v_x, v_y) \cdot dt$ can be represented with a RVE with covariance $\Sigma_1 = dt^2 \cdot \Sigma_v$. So, I have to compute the covariance of the sum of two RVE (namely $X$ and $Y$), the first with covariance $\Sigma_p$, the second with covariance $\Sigma_1$.

Ok, let's try to do it:

$cov(X+Y) = E((X+Y)(X+Y)^T) - E(X+Y)E(X+Y)^T$
$= E((X+Y)(X^T+Y^T)) - E(X+Y)E(X^T+Y^T)$
$= E(XX^T + YY^T + XY^T + YX^T) - (E(X)E(Y))(E(X^T)E(Y^T))$
$= E(XX^T)-E(X)E(X^T) + E(YY^T)-E(Y)E(Y^T) + E(XY^T)-E(X)E(Y^T) + E(YX^T)-E(Y)E(X^T)$
$= cov(X) + cov(Y) + E(XY^T)-E(X)E(Y^T) + E(YX^T)-E(Y)E(X^T)$

Is it correct?
Now, can I rewrite the formulation in order to compute $cov(X+Y)$ only in function of $cov(X)$ and $cov(Y)$ since I do not have the PDF of $X$ and $Y$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You've mentioned that you can assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, in which case all the terms in your expression other than $\operatorname{Var}(X)$ and $\operatorname{Var}(Y)$ cancel.

Are you sure independence is a good assumption for your use case? Why do you want to estimate the variance of $X+Y$? is it to estimate the error of your prediction? In that case I wonder if you could estimate a confidence interval in a better way (here it seems you will make a gaussian assumption to give a CI).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Basically $X$ represents the initial position of the object and $Y= (v_x, v_y) \cdot dt$ represents the forwarding vector. Since the estimation of the velocity depends on the history of the object positions, they are not indenpendent. I made this assumption to semplifiy (it is common in my field). Anyway, yes I want to compute the $cov(X + Y)$ to estimate the error in the final predicted position. Since I represent the final prediction with a 2D gaussian distribution, I would like to estimate the covariance matrix to embed it in the gaussian. I'm open to suggestion.

Comment: However I have a question. You stated that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent $cov(X+Y) = cov(X) + cov(Y)$. But why all the other terms cancel out? I mean for example $E(X)E(Y)^T$ is not 0 to me. It's just the product of the expections.

Comment: In that case, the remaining terms are just 2 times the covariance of $X$ and $Y$. Do you have some way to estimate that?

Comment: I'd expect the Gaussian CI to not have the coverage you need, I expect that the literature has some methods for estimating a CI directly. Maybe check the SLAM literature?

Comment: To answer your followup question, if they're independent then the expectation of the product reduces to the product of the expectations.

Comment: Ok, thank you! Your suggestion of SLAM is nice. Remembering Kalman filter prediction step $x_{t+1} = Ax_t + Bv_t + \epsilon_t $, where $A=I$ in my case and $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, R_t)$. So basically when we estimate the covariance $\Sigma_{t+1} = \Sigma_t + R_t$ that will reduce to $cov(X+Y) = cov(X) + cov(Y)$ in my case. It would be correct, isn't it?